# Jenkins: pass (environment) variable to Docker while building the image

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-plugins

We are using [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) to **build** and deploy Docker containers.

I am using a variable ($ENVIRONMENT) inside the **Dockerfile**. How can I set this variable from Jenkins? Something like `ENVIRONMENT=test|live`. The variable must be available *inside* the docker container afterwards.

Or in other words:
How can I achieve [this](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6822#issuecomment-168170031) from within Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your jenkins job has control over the `docker run` command used to launch containers, you can use the [`docker run` -e option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables)

> the operator can set any environment variable in the container by using one or more `-e` flags

Those variables would then be available in the (launched) docker container.

In other words, you do a late binding (at runtime) of those variables.

Comment: I refactored my code to access the $ENVIRONMENT variable on `run` but I thought it would be cleaner to put the right config file into the image on build as images get tagged with test|live.

Comment: @kev if your job does build an image, then you can use ENV: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env: that will be memorized in the image, and then passed to the container on docker run.

Comment: If I would hardcode the environment variable in the Dockerfile, I would need one per environment.